# How query firebase database and retrieve specific data

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Database structure]

If I query database child `Readings`, I have all items, but if I add a condition, I don't have results.

Someone can help me make the query in order to get all the elements that have the value `"2020-9-23"` (this will be chosen by the user)?

Thank you

```
mDatabase!!.child("Readings").child("dia").equalTo("2020-9-23").orderByValue().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        
        val data: ArrayList<EnergyReading> = ArrayList()
        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
            for (snapshot: DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                try {
                    data.add(EnergyReading(snapshot.child("reading")))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            mReadingList = data
            Log.i("ReadingModel","data updated there are " + mReadingList!!.size + " Reading in the list")
        } else {
            throw Exception("data snapshot is null line 31")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `dia` property is under `reading`, you need to order on `reading/dia`:

```
mDatabase!!.child("Readings").orderByChild("reading/dia").equalTo("2020-9-23").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
```

Comment: This solution don't work for me.

Return "DataSnapshot{key = dia, value = null }"

Comment: Sorry about that, you actually need `orderByChild()`. Queries in Firebase are at least two stages: 1) order on some value that exists in a fixed location under each child node with `orderBy...`, 2) then filter and limit the child nodes with `equalTo`, `startAt` and/or `endAt`.

Comment: That's right. I had to remove the last orderByValue because it was giving an error. But now it’s working. Thank you very much @Frank van Puffelen.